# Why is hexacyanoferrate(II) colored and at the same time diamagnetic?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals, color, magnetism

I am wondering why $\ce{[Fe(CN)6]^4-}$ is colored and at the same time diamagnetic. For a transition metal to be diamagnetic all the electrons should be paired up in the d orbitals and at the same time a transition metal is colored because certain wavelength of a white light is absorbed during the electron movement to a higher energy d orbital.

With regard to this, I see a paradox. Since $\ce{[Fe(CN)6]^4-}$ is colored, it means that electron movement happened. If there has been an electron movement, not all the electrons of $\ce{[Fe(CN)6]^4-}$ are paired up

However, why is $\ce{[Fe(CN)6]^4-}$ still considered diamagnetic?

Comment: Have you heard about charge transfer phenomena (Ligand-Metal, Metal-ligand, Inter Valence etc.) ?

Comment: Color does not indicate the presence of unpaired electrons by itself.

Comment: The ground state ion is $d^6$ and low spin which means that there are 3 pairs of electrons in the $t_{2g}$ orbitals. On absorbing a photon an electron gets promoted to the $e_g$ orbital: this gives the compound its colour. This _excited state_ species has unpaired electrons but like all excited states is relatively short lived and will decay back to the ground state. In any sample the number of excited state is tiny compared to the ground state so we can simply ignore the number of excited states.